# Problem with updates in elementary OS

Tags: updates

I am having these problems with the newly installed elementary OS. The * in the details represent 'http://' When i was updating I got this, the details are below

[image: error when trying to update]

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150411)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150411)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150411)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150411)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch *ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch *ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be solved by opening Software-Center -> Edit -> Software origin and delete the cd (install from cd). If the system asks, put in your root nick, close the merged little window and wait till the end of the job of Software-Center. Update your system.

Comment: Thanks , I somehow managed to delete that cd thing and all is fine now :)